Pointwise convergence of almost periodic function
This question is inspired by this post and definitions I use can be found there. The definition of $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ can be found in this wiki:
Fix $f$ a real-valued almost periodic (but not periodic) function. For each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, define $f_t(x) = f(x-t)$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. By the definition of an almost periodic function, $\overline{\{f_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}}^{\|\cdot\|_{\infty}}$the closure of the set $\{f_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is compact with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ the supremum norm. As a result, for any $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$, $\overline{\{g_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}}^{\|\cdot\|_{\infty}}$ is not compact.
My question is the following: could there be a $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g$ is a clustered point of the set $\{f_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ with respect to the pointwise convergence topology or the weak topology? Since the set of translation of a function from $\partial \overline{\{f_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}}^{\|\cdot\|_{\infty}}$ the boundary points of $\{f_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$, is not necessarily included in $\{f_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$, then I wonder when I choose a topology that is properly weaker than the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$-topology, if I can find a function whose set of translation is "large" enough to be non-compact.

Can you recall what is $C_0(\mathbb R)$?

It is the set of continuous functions that vanish in the infinity. Namely: $$ C_0(\mathbb{R}) = \big{ f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\text{  continuous  }: \lim_{t\rightarrow \pm \infty}\vert, f(t),\vert = 0\big}$$

Put $K=\overline{\{f_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}}^{\|\cdot\|_{\infty}}$. Since the set $K$ is compact in the given set $X$ of functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, with the topology $\tau_\infty$, induced by the
the supremum norm, the set $K$ is compact in $X$ endowed with any topology $\tau$ weaker then $\tau_\infty$. Therefore, if $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff then $K$ is closed in $(X,\tau)$. Therefore
$\overline{\{f_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}}^\tau=K$.

Thanks for your answer. Then the question boils down to if there is a $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g$ is in the boundary point of $\overline{{f_t}{t\in \mathbb{R}}}^{|\cdot|{\infty}}$.

@Sanae If $K\ni g$ then $K\supset \overline{{g_t}{t\in \mathbb{R}}}^{|\cdot|{\infty}}$. If $g\in C_0(\mathbb R)$ then it is easy to see that the latter set is compact iff $g$ is the zero function.

I am sorry if I mix the definition. I mean to look for a topology $\tau$ such that $\tau_{\infty}\subseteq \tau$. I suppose I am looking for a "finer" topology but not a "weaker" one. Namely, I am looking for a topology $\tau$ where convergence with respect to $\tau$ does not imply convergence $\tau_{\infty}$.

In other words, I wonder if the closure of ${f_t}{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ with respect to $\tau$ will intersect $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ when $\tau$ is the pointwise convergence topology or the weak topology (the one defined by bounded linear functionals of $C_0(\mathbb{R})$. As you point out, the $\tau{\infty}$ closure of ${f_t}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is disjoint from $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ as not $f_t$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$ near infinity.

@Sanae
When the topology $\tau$ is natural, there are not so many possibilities for $K^\tau=\overline{{f_t}{t\in \mathbb{R}}}^\tau$. Namely, as I already wrote in my answer, if $\tau\subset\tau\infty$ and $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff then $K$ is closed in $(X,\tau)$ and so $K^\tau=K$. On the other hand, the topology $\tau_\infty$ is already rather strong, but if $\tau\supset\tau_\infty$ then $K^\tau\subset K$.

You are correct. It is me who completely mixed the definition. I shall instead start from a topology weaker than $|\cdot|_{\infty}$.
